# Frequently can't access Virtualmin via browser

Tags: centos

I have a CentOS 5 server over at Digital Ocean which has Virtualmin installed. Virtualmin is accessed by visiting https://ipaddress:10000 but that URL almost always returns "Google Chrome's connection attempt to ipaddresshere was rejected."

- I can ping the IP address.
- I can view all the websites hosted at that IP.
- I can SSH into the server.

According to the Digital Ocean dashboard:

- ~10% CPU
- <.01 Mbps bandwidth

According to the Virtualmin dashboard:

- Real Memory: 311.24 MB used, 497.85 MB total
- Disk space: 2.70 GB used, 19.69 GB total

**If I restart the droplet/server (sudo shutdown -r now), I can then access Virtualmin via https://ipaddress:10000 once the server comes back online.**

**Questions:**

- What would cause Virtualmin to be inaccessible via the web?
- Is there a server log I can review to see why my connections were denied?
- **Is there a, *hopefully simple*, fix for this?**

Answer (score 1):

**It appears that there is a bug in Webmin that is causing it to not start with the server.**

Running 'netstat -an | grep '10000' returned nothing which implied the server wasn't listening to port 10000.

I then checked webmin status by running "sudo service webmin status". This did **not** return "Webmin (pid #####) is running".

**SOLUTION: "sudo service webmin start"**

Comment: Didn't help for me unfortunately. Should have just shell some dough and go with cPanel -sigh- webmin is really good but really hard to maintain if you're not familiar with Unix (like me).